# I am not able to read authorization headers on server side with reactjs fetch and nodejs as REST apis project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not able to get headers on server side with reactjs fetch as way of calling api on front end. in old project it was working fine
what could be reason of that as my back-end code is not changed

```
      this.setState({ isProcessing: true });  
      fetch(env.apis.getUsersList, reqOptions)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ users: data });  
      })
      .catch((error) => {
           debugger
      });
   }
```

and this is how i passing header

```
var reqOptions = {
        method: actionType,
        headers: new Headers({ 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.token
       }), 
    };
    // debugger
    // if (localStorage.token) {
        // reqOptions.headers.authorization = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.token;   
    // }
    if (data) {
        reqOptions.body = JSON.stringify(data);
    }
    return reqOptions;
```

getting this error message
***error = TypeError: Failed to fetch***

in browser it is basically showing ***provisional headers are being shown***

that is error

[image]

Comment: "Authotization"

Comment: what you saying ?

Comment: Instead of adding the "method" and "headers" to reqOptions, just add `var reqOptions = {authorization: "Bearer"+ localstorage.token}`

Comment: yes also tried this without success

Comment: I changed theme to new one and now this is occuring. maybe issue with reactjs version or sone setting.

Comment: How are you getting the headers in the backend? also, I think you are trying to send data to the backend through headers right? try using queries. if you are using express, access this with `req.query`. In the frontend change the fetch URL to `"env.apis.getUsersList"+"?authorization=Bearer"+localStorage.token`

Comment: no I not sending data through headers. I using nodejs in backend and enabled authorization header

Comment: I posted image in my question as well to understand the error in better way

Comment: The error message you are showing indicates this was a cross-origin request. By default, browsers will not include credentails (such as an `Authorization` header unless the server responds with appropriate CORS headers. Right now, the error is ocurring during a preflight (OPTIONS) request (check the `Network` tab in your browser console). Since your server didn't return the appropriate headers in the preflight, the actual POST was never sent.

Comment: You should read up on how to submit cross-origin requests using fetch: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: when I used cors package of node js then it worked like that

var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({credentials: true}));

Comment: @rfestag  you are right issue was in server side. but that was working fine with last theme

Comment: @rfestag 
post your answer so i can mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue was on server side with the CORS settings for nodejs and fixed doing like that

```
var cors = require('cors'); 
app.use(cors({credentials: true}));
```